# Authenticate with Office365 as a Onenote plugin

Tags: authentication, office365-apps, onenote-api

How can I get an authentication token without requiring an Office365 user to sign in? (sign in *again*, that is - assume the user is signed into Onenote with OneDrive) I would like to create a Onenote plugin utilising semi-new API features for teachers ([here](https://blogs.office.com/2016/02/17/automate-onenote-class-notebook-creation-and-roster-changes-with-new-apis/)).

Microsoft released a plugin early on in their branch of Onenote schools support that added basic buttons as a Onenote toolbar but they only lead to the online interface. I'm under the impression it then isn't possible to get a token from within Onenote.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this capability does not exist yet. In order to be able to call the OneNote API, the user will have to sign in and give your app permissions. This is obviously not the ideal user experience, but currently there is no way around it.

The closest example I can think of is the meeting details button in the home tab in OneNote Web. It calls outlook APIs and therefore needs to be able to sign the user in.

On the positive side, once the user is signed in, you can store the refresh token in a cookie (remember to encrypt and mark it for expiration) and he/she will not have to sign in again in that browser.

[image: Meeting details]